# export-csv.js and shiny app

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export-to-csv, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm using shinyApp with the highcharts (pie chart type). I want to allow the user to export the chart as CSV and jpg also. I added the exporting.js script and it works (but only contain to export the chart as a picture). I tried to add also the export-csv.js

(like here: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/cqjvd/ `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://highcharts.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js"></script>`)

but nothing changed.
I added the scripts in the following form:

tags$head( tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "exporting.js" ) ),

tags$head( tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "export-csv.js") ) ,

Comment: @Victorp - any suggestions ?

Comment: @Pork Chop - any suggestions ?

Comment: @Yihui any suggestions ?